# Some custom filed of contact can not work on android4.0

Tags: android, xml, contacts

I add an account to account&sync,the xml of ContactsSource is below, it can work normal on android2.3,but on android4.0.3,the "android:icon" and "android:summaryColumn" fields can not work.On contact detail page of addressbook,the connections section shows the icon of the account,not "@drawable/icon_bb" and the summaryColumn shows the account name,not "data2" in xml.

```
<ContactsDataKind
    android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.com.android.bb.profile"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon_bb"
    android:summaryColumn="data2"
    android:detailColumn="data3"
    android:detailSocialSummary="true" />
```

Comment: I faced the same problem, does anybody resolve that..

Comment: Same problem here on 4.3

Answer (score 0):

Two tweaks here:

1st you have to switch `detailColumn` with `summaryColumn` for Ice Cream Sandwitch. Just put another contacts.xml into res/xml-v14 folder

```
<ContactsDataKind
 ...
 android:summaryColumn="data3"
 android:detailColumn="data2"
 ... />
```

2nd to make icon work you have to set icon for intent-filter at `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<intent-filter android:icon="@drawable/icon_bb" >
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.com.android.bb.profile"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add the `<ContactsAccountType>` to the following:    `viewStreamItemActivity="com.test.Activity"` (this is the full path of your activity that will receive the intent when users click on the line item). Sample:

```
<ContactsAccountType xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" viewStreamItemActivity="com.test.Activity">

  <ContactsDataKind android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.com.android.bb.profile" android:icon="@drawable/icon_bb" android:summaryColumn="data2" android:detailColumn="data3" android:detailSocialSummary="true" />

</ContactsAccountType>
```

Once you have this you need to add in the manifest an intent filter for the icon inside the activity (com.test.Activity). Sample:

```
<activity android:name=".Activity" android:label="@string/title_activity_main">
  <intent-filter android:icon="@drawable/icon_bb">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.com.android.bb.profile" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```